# Avoid .show() in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a pandas dataframe df, I would like to be able to do the following from terminal:

`df.plot()`

and have the plot show up in a window automatically, without having to also to the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; 
plt.show()
```

Is it doable?

Answer (score 2):

You can [enable interactive mode](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ion.html) when you're in the interactive Python session:

```py
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.ion()
```

You can also make that permanent, so you don't have to type `plt.ion()` every time you start a new session. Just look for "interactive" in your [`matplotlibrc` configuration file](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) and change that line to this:

```
interactive: True
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The change in the configuration file did not work for some reason, but adding plt.ion() in the ipython startup file did

Comment: Ah, okay. You didn't mention IPython, I thought you meant the standard Python interpreter. Lots of IDEs have their own way of enabling this. Like in Spyder and Jupyter (I think) this works out of the box.

Comment: true, I sometimes launch ipython from terminal and the one you suggested is the only solution that worked